# How to attach local functions to document events in Javascript constructor?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to attach to document movemove event in a constructor:

**f.js:**

```
function F() {
    var HandleMouseMove = function (event) {
        //this is never called
    };

    $(function () {
        // HandleMouseMove seems to be null at this point
        $(document).mousemove(HandleMouseMove);
    });
}
```

this is instantiated in another file

**app.js**

```
$(function () {
    var f = new F();
});
```

However when I debug this, the HandleMouseMove function reference seems to be null in the callback. Subsequently it never gets called.

How to attach local functions to document events?

Comment: That doesn't make sense - `$(function () {` directs jQuery to run that function on document load. It should be in the top level, not inside a class.

Comment: Apart from missing a closing bracket in app.js, this should work..

Comment: @keith the bracket is just a typo when retyping the simplified version here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something else going on here, there was the missing `bracket` in your app.js, that you say was just a typo.  So here is a working snippet that seems fine,.  It's not in two separate js files, but that should not matter as long as your loading the scripts in the correct order.

```js
function F() {
    var HandleMouseMove = function (event) {
        //this is never called
        console.log("called");
    };

    $(function () {
        // HandleMouseMove seems to be null at this point
        $(document).mousemove(HandleMouseMove);
    });
}

$(function () {
    var f = new F();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: there indeed is something else going on. The mousemove event is not capturing mouse move over all elements for some reason, I will have to figure out why. Thank you for the second pair of eyes. I think we can close this question as completely nonconstructive

Comment: there was an iframe embedded in the current page, mousemove over that iframe is not captured this way